# Why are there different STRING formats?

Tags: string, snmp

When some time ago I had developed a script to query network interfaces via `snmpwalk` and `IF-MIB::ifDescr` the output format was like `STRING: eth0`.
The OS was SLES11 using net-snmp (it still works in SLES12 using net-snmp-5.7.3).

However on a different OS (still Linux) the interface strings are represented as `STRING: "port1"` (note the surrounding double-quotes).
Now the question is: Who is responsible for the extra double quotes? A different version of net-snmp, or a different SNMP agent? Or is one of the results incorrectly implemented in the agent?

As far as I understand SNMP the double quotes are **not** necessary for the protocol as strings are always transmitted with their length.

Comment: Use a tool like Wireshark to go deep into the packets. That should tell where the quotes come from. Even if they come from the agent, you cannot say "incorrectly" as the actual developers can have their own reasons.

Comment: Actually if the developers were free to add or do not add double quotes around strings, it would be a lack of proper SNMP MIB specification IMHO.

Comment: IETF RFC documents (not only SNMP related ones) are loose, and vendor specific behaviors are common. So be caution if your application talks to devices from multiple vendors and be prepared for such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it would be unusual (and undesirable) for an SNMP Agent to provide a *quoted* string in response to a query for `ifDescr` (or for anything else!) as they are indeed not part of the contract of a string at that level, the SNMP world is rife with oddities and variations and specification deviations, so this is not something you can assume will never happen.

Meanwhile, the format of the command-line output of a tool like Net-SNMP is effectively arbitrary: the developers can choose whether or not to quote strings, and as long as they document their choice, the end result is the same. So you cannot make any assumptions here either.

You should examine the actual data. You can do this by sniffing the SNMP packets with a tool like `tcpdump` and loading them into a UI like Wireshark (previously Ethereal). Then you can observe the *actual* contents of the datagram without the Net-SNMP formatting. If it contains quotes, it's the agent's fault; if it doesn't, the app is adding them for display.

*(There's probably a Net-SNMP flag to make it display the bytes, in hex form, making up the string, which would be an easier way to gather this evidence if I remembered what the flag was.)*

As an editorial note, if you'd told us what the "different" Linux OS *actually* was, and what version of Net-SNMP you were using on it, we could have confirmed (or ruled out) option two for you.

*(For what it's worth, I'm not aware of any Net-SNMP change that added or removed quotation marks from the command-line output, so this is* probably *an oddity of the agent on that "different" system.)*

Comment: I would have liked to provide more information, but the environment is restricted: I have agents **A** and **B**  and managers **C** and **D**. Unfortunately I only have full access to **A** and **C**, while **D** cannot access **A**, and **C** cannot access **B**. **A** is the same machine as **C** (SLES 12 SP4), while **D** is some Debian variant (I was only asked to help there) and **B** is some embedded system running Linux. The only information I can get from **B** is what SNMP provides. From the version numbers, I guess that **C** and **D** use the same version of net-snmp.